Error ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg con pyscopg2 y Python 3.13
Tengo un error y no estoy pudiendo probar una conexión a PostgreSQL. El codigo Python es muy simple, es el siguiente:
import psycopg2

conexion = psycopg2.connect(user="usuario",
                            password="clave",
                            host="192.168.3.15",
                            port="5432",
                            database="test_db")
cursor = conexion.cursor()
query = """select * from public.personas"""
cursor.execute(query)

for fila in cursor:
    print(fila)

cursor.close()
conexion.close()


Previamente instale primero Pyscopg2 con el comando:
pip install psycopg2
Codigo de salida cuando ejecuto el comando anterior:
(SQL) PS F:\AppsDev\python\Test_SQL> pip install psycopg2
Collecting psycopg2
  Downloading psycopg2-2.9.10.tar.gz (385 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
  Building wheel for psycopg2 (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for psycopg2: filename=psycopg2-2.9.10-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl size=141777 sha256=8470b9317fe23de85173aebc40f593c55102721ac0a4822b59d7e41e90bdaf52
  Stored in directory: c:\users\pecodedev\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\d1\02\6b\6fab072a7ac365814e6d6217fef5525fa5ac3c64204a418040
Successfully built psycopg2
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
Successfully installed psycopg2-2.9.10
(SQL) PS F:\AppsDev\python\Test_SQL>

Se instala normal, pero al ejecutar el codigo me tira el error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\AppsDev\python\Test_SQL\test_pgsql.py", line 1, in <module>
    import psycopg2
  File "F:\AppsDev\python\Test_SQL\SQL\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
    ...<10 lines>...
    )
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.

Si hago el comando: pip show psycopg2
mi da lo siguiente:
Name: psycopg2
Version: 2.9.10
Summary: psycopg2 - Python-PostgreSQL Database Adapter
Home-page: https://psycopg.org/
Author: Federico Di Gregorio
Author-email: fog@initd.org
License: LGPL with exceptions
Location: F:\AppsDev\python\Test_SQL\SQL\Lib\site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:

He buscado en la web y algunos sugieren instalar la version binaria, asi que quite la version psycopg2 y probe instalando...
pip install psycopg2-binary
Y da el mismo error.
No pude encontrar nada mas sobre este error. No tengo instalado Panda, ni django, tampoco anaconda ni conda. Todo esto esta en un entorno virtual.
Comentario: la primera vez que quise instalar psycopg2 no pude porque faltaban los Redistributable de Visual C++ 14, así que descargue visual studio build tools 2022 e instale solo lo mínimo básico que marca por defecto cuando se elige "Desarrollo para el escritorio con C++".
Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida!
Muchas Gracias!

Puedes mostrar la terminal y como haces la instalación de "psycopg2" ??

pip show psycopg2 o pip show psycopg2-binary

listo, ahi lo agregue!

Cuál era el problema ?

A menos que estés manteniendo código antiguo, ¿y si pruebas con psycopg 3? Según el propio repositorio de la versión 2 dice: Psycopg 3 is the evolution of psycopg2. Para instalarlo, no hay que poner número de versión, más información: Pypi

No no lo habia solucionado, solo te habia dicho que agregue lo que me pediste en la publicacion de arriba. Pero no sabia que existia una version 3, estoy siguiendo un curso online que se hizo hace unos 2 años. Instale la ultima versión con pip install psycopg y tuve que cambiar los parametros  en el connect y me anduvo! Aunque por lo que probe rapidamente parece q solo funciona con el "host=localhost" o "host=127.0.0.1"... si pongo la IP de la pc no me conecta.. debe venir por la config del servidor... ya investigare... Muchas Gracias, me ayudaste a solucionarlo!

Psycopg2 aun es mantenido pero parece que no es compatible con python 3.13 en windows por ahora (a la espera de que una dependencia se actualize a Py 3.13), ver https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1736
